# Why didn't X-24 regenerate?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

X-24 is a clone of Wolverine. Wolverine is basically immortal if not for long term Adamantium poisoning. Wolverine, in one timeline, has been shot in the head with Adamantium with only minor effects. In the source material, he's been reduced to a single cell and regenerated. He's been decapitated and dismembered. Even with Adamantium limiting his healing factor, he's the hardest sob to kill in any universe.

So why does a single bullet shatter his head like that, killing X-24 instantly instead of regenerating? He should be able to regenerate in a few hours or days without a problem. After all, he has only been around and with Adamantium  for months or years, no where near as long as the original (50 years of Adamantium until death, roughly) so he shouldn't have a compromised healing factor. **Has production explained the discrepancy?**

Comment: Maybe X-24 can survive and come in future films if they can make him sign more films.

Comment: Maybe he **did** regenerate in a few hours, but we can't be sure as it was never shown. But now his boss is dead, so I don't know what will happen to him...

Comment: Isn't there a rule against spoilers in the title of a question? Please edit!

Comment: Actually, it [_is_ a rule](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that spoilers shouldn't be in question titles: "we make every effort to remove spoilers from Question Titles which is one part of the site that does not have mark-up capabilities and is out in the open."

Comment: @KutuluMike nice edit

Comment: Some people would even go as far as downvoting a question that clearly violates the policy of avoiding spoilers in question titles, even more so if the user is aware of that policy. But I don't regard that a proper attitude towards the problem and editing in the way KutuluMike did is preferable and fortunately already solved the problem.

Comment: X-24 is not perfect and perhaps not exactly like Logan. In the scene after the farm incident, his creator Dr. Rice, mentions that he is "new" and not quite ready and that he needs to take the Serum to "help him heal".

Comment: For the record, in the comics Wolverine cannot regenerate from a single cell - that was a one-time incident, and it was an alien crystal that regenerated him... not his healing factor. If his head were to be blown off or destroyed somehow, he would be just as dead as you or me.

Comment: Related: [Are the adamantium rules from previous Wolverine movies now not canon after “Logan”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154764/8043)

Answer (score 9):

As I mentioned in the related question on [the sister site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154764/are-the-adamantium-rules-from-previous-wolverine-movies-now-not-canon-after-log), the only way in which this discrepancy has been explained is that the producers of *Logan* openly admit that they ignored continuity for the sake of story.

As James Mangold explained in [this interview](http://screencrush.com/james-mangold-logan-timeline/):

> In order to make a different Logan, and a different tone of a Wolverine movie, we felt like we couldn’t hold on to every tradition established in all the movies religiously, or we’d be trapped by the decisions made before us

Otherwise, we are left to speculate on why X-24 might be vulnerable to an adamantium bullet to the head when Wolverine was not. It's possibly there's an in-universe explanation (for example, Alkali may have intentionally left an Achilles Heel in X-24 in case he pulled the same stunt Logan did), but the movie never tells us what that is.

Comment: For one thing, you see the bullet exit the other side, ripping his skull wide  open (with metal visibly splayed out) . Maybe X-24 can't survive with that kind of permanent damage to his head.

Comment: @Jack his regular bone skull and brain tissue should regenerate... That's the question.

Comment: Note that the movie also renegotiates Wolverine's healing factor in its very premise. Instead of being unstoppable and capable of regenerating a full Wolverine from a single cell, it has failed him and he is dying of adamantium poisoning, something that's just unthinkable in a comic book continuity. The whole premise of the movie requires that Wolverine's healing factor has its limits.

Comment: He's currently dead of Adamantium poisoning in mainstream 616 comic continuity...

Answer (score 5):

There is no indication in the film that X-24 is actually dead. He was shot and then collapsed, but that's the last we saw of him. For all we know, he could have regenerated after some time had elapsed.

As to why he didn't attack the kids if he regenerated, perhaps it took him much longer than Logan to recuperate because he was just a clone. Or maybe he pulled a 'Regarding Henry' and became a nice guy after being shot. In any case, there was no explicit answer in the movie.